# cucumber test - Which syntax to choose to test a radio button selection?

Tags: ruby, radio-button, sinatra, cucumber

I'm fairly new to coding and learning Ruby and Sinatra at the moment.
I've started to work on a Rock paper scissors game for the terminal that I'm trying to export to the web and am using cucumber to test its web functionalities.

I have a web functionality integrated with an erb file, which funnily enough works in the web, but I cannot find the cucumber web steps/syntax that actually make it pass and shows that it works. I want to code the right way so would like my test to actually work before I proceed to new functionalities.

My options.erb file has these lines:

```
<form action="game_play">
  <fieldset>
    Which game do you want to play?<br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="RPS" checked>Rock Paper Scissors<br>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="RPSSL">Rock Paper Scissors Spock Lizard
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="PLAY!">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

my Sinatra server includes the following

```
get '/game_play' do
  @type = params[:type]
  erb :play
end
```

and in the play.erb page, rock, paper and scissors are automatically displayed but only this if-statement

```
<% if @type == "RPSSL" %>
```

allows spock and lizard to appear. In the web, if I rackup and go on localhost:9292, it works; only selecting RPSSL allows to see spock and lizard on the next page.

These cucumber tests

```
Scenario: Choosing a RPS type of game
  Given I am on the options page
  When I check "Rock Paper Scissors" within "type"
  And I press "PLAY!"
  Then I should see "Rock"
  But I should not see "Spock"

Scenario: Choosing a RPSSL type of game
  Given I am on the options page
  When I check "Rock Paper Scissors Spock Lizard" within "type"
  And I press "PLAY!"
  Then I should see "Rock"
  And I should see "Spock"
```

are not working. The first one actually passes because RPS is checked by default but check may not be the right cucumber syntax. I tried with select, Choose, even fill in but despite spending a long time on the web, cannot find the right cucumber syntax for a radio button. Would anybody be able to help? Thanks.

Comment: hey @Guillame - can you provide more information about your cucumber steps?  Also a link to your repo with the relevant code would be really valuable too in helping you to solve this

Comment: Hi Sam. Sure. I'm using the standard cucumber web steps so far and here is the [link](https://github.com/GBouffard/rps-challenge)

Comment: all cucumber tests are green on that repo's master branch ... please see my analysis of how to post on SO in such a fashion to maximize the chances of people helping you https://github.com/marcinwal/githubTree/wiki :-)

Comment: Thanks Sam. I thought it was bad practice to push some broken code on Github and that's why I didn't push a failing test (which I described above instead). the link you provided is very useful. Thanks

Comment: broken code can go in a feature branch if you want to share it @Guillame Bouffard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so one thing is that you should really delete websteps and write your own, but let's look at the code that supports checking in websteps:

https://github.com/GBouffard/rps-challenge/blob/master/features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb#L76

```
When /^(?:|I )check "([^\"]*)"(?: within "([^\"]*)")?$/ do |field, selector|
  with_scope(selector) do
    check(field)
  end
end
```

also you should really show us the actual error you get, but I suspect from your cucumber step `When I check "Rock Paper Scissors Spock Lizard" within "type"` that there is some mislabeling in the actual checkbox label.

This is kind of issue that I would attack with byebug to check that the correct HTML element is being grabbed ...

Okay, so getting in there with byebug and doing a deep dive in the capybara source I think I've fixed it.  If one looks at the capybara tests on how to use 'radio buttons' which is what you are using here, you need something like this

```
<td><input type="radio" name="type" value="RPS" id="RPS" class="regular-checkbox" checked />
<label for="RPS">Rock Paper Scissors</label><br><br><img src="/images/rps_button.jpg"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="type" value="RPSSL" id="RPSSL" class="regular-checkbox"/>
<label for="RPSSL">Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock<br><br><img src="/images/rpssl_button.jpg"></td>
```

and you need to update your scenarios as follows to ensure you are "choosing" a "radio button" rather than "checking it"

```
  Scenario: Choosing a RPS type of game
    Given I am on the homepage
    When I fill in "name" with "Guillaume"
    And I press "START"
    And I choose "Rock Paper Scissors"
    And I press "PLAY!"
    Then I should see "Rock"
    But I should not see "Spock"

  Scenario: Choosing a RPSSL type of game
    Given I am on the options page
    When I choose "Rock Paper Scissors Spock Lizard"
    And I press "PLAY!"
    Then I should see "Rock"
    And I should see "Spock"
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sam. It definitely solved my problem :)